# Выборка значений таблицы по списку

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

Есть коллекция List, хранящая значения некоторых Id. Как реализовать выборку в Entity Framework согласно этого списка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим у вас есть

```
List<int> ListID
```

Тогда используйте

```
context.Model.Where(x => ListID.contains(x.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: Благодарю. Смотрел на одно, видел другое.